# SQL Server Global Temporary Table Locking

Tags: sql, sql-server, global-temp-tables

How do I lock a global temporary table in a stored procedure that's getting created and populated by a `SELECT INTO` statement? For example:

```
SELECT * 
INTO ##TempEmployee   
FROM Employee
```

This stored procedure is executed for generating reports and it's there in every client database (multi-tenant architecture using different DB per client). I do not want data in this global temporary table to be shared between clients when the report is generated concurrently. I don't have a choice but to use global temp table because I use it for generating columns on the fly using PIVOT.

Comment: And why is that a reason for a global temp table?

Comment: I too am confused why that requires a global temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not include it inside a `transaction block` like

```
begin transaction
SELECT * 
INTO ##TempEmployee   
FROM Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**WorkDummySQL**

```
  create table rr(id integer,name varchar(20))
    insert into rr values(1,'aa')
    select * from rr
```

**Tempdb**

> select * into ##ta from WorkDummySQL.dbo.rr